# InetAddress.getByName causes NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, runnable

realizing I had to worry about a network based thread causing havoc on my UI thread, I went through the whole process of creating a custom handler and custom thread for my TCP/IP network ping pong of commands and responses between my app and the remote server.  Worked great. (you'll see it referenced in the code below as `mainCommunicationThread(controlCommands);`)

Before that thread/handler is triggered though, I pull the IP or Hostname from SQL, (calling it currIPstr) and then send that off with a bunch of other variables to the thread/handler.
The one thing I need to do though, is ensure that it's either A) a valid IP address, or B) that the hostname is resolved -- otherwise, there's no point in even starting the attempt.

Ok, no problem, I just call this:

```
currIP = InetAddress.getByName(currIPstr).toString().split("/")[1];
```

What I've just tripped across though, is that with Gingerbread or StrictMode running, the above line triggers the dreaded NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Yup, that simple call to InetAddress.getByName is enough.  Well, I've been fighting with a work around, so I moved the whole function inside a runnable:

```
private String currStatIP = null;
private String currentStatIPstr = null;
private Integer currentStatIDstr = -1;
private String currentPort = null;
private String currentLocation = null;
private String currUserName = null;
private String currPassword = null;
private Integer currStatID = -1;
public void StatControl(Cursor c, final String[] commandtosend){


    /*the object will always start off with the first 4 fields being the current login information.
     * [0] = IP Address
     * [1] = port number
     * [2] = username
     * [3] = password
     * [4] = COMMAND -- this will be used in a switchcase inside the pingpong to decide what to do.
     *               -- if the Socket is not open, the first 4 fields will be used to re-initiate the connection
     *               -- otherwise, the command is drawn from this field and sent directly.
     * */


    currentStatIDstr = c.getInt(0);
    currentStatIPstr = c.getString(1);
    currentPort = c.getString(2);
    currentLocation = c.getString(3);
    currUserName = c.getString(4);
    currPassword = c.getString(5);
    currStatID = currentStatIDstr;


    Handler networkLookupHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable networkLookupRunnable = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try {
                    currStatIP = InetAddress.getByName(currentStatIPstr).toString().split("/")[1];
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             int portNumber = 0;
                try {
                    portNumber = Integer.parseInt(currentPort);
                } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                   nfe.printStackTrace();
                }
                String userName = currUserName;
                String passWord = currPassword;
                String[] command = commandtosend;

                Object[] controlCommands = new Object[]{
                        currStatID,
                        currStatIP, //InetAddress of String representing the IP address
                        portNumber,     //int representation of the port number, taken from String
                        currentLocation,
                        userName,
                        passWord,
                        command
                        };
                /*for(int i=0;i<controlCommands.length;i++){
                    Log.d("object work","controlCommands[" + i + "] is " + controlCommands[i]);
                }*/

                mainCommunicationThread(controlCommands);
         }   
    };
    networkLookupHandler.post(networkLookupRunnable);
}
```

and, YAY!  It worked! I'm not getting the NetworkOnMainThreadException anymore.
Oh... wait.. yes I am.

The above does NOT trigger an exception on API 10, 12, 14, even 16 works fine in the emulator, However, if I load it onto my Samsung Google Galaxy Nexus running Jellybean 4.1.1, I get the NetworkOnMainThreadException crash.  Even with the above wrapped inside the runnable.

I'm at a total loss as to how to fix this.

Comment: how on earth do you expect to resolve domain names without network connection ? (there may be case where it does not, which are when the domain is in cache, or when you give it an ip for name)

Comment: in most case, handler.post will run on the ui thread (unless you create a looper for it)

Comment: seriously @njzk2 ?  I haven't (obviously) dug too far into all the caveats of threads/handlers

Got an example of "creating a looper for handler.post"?

Comment: no, because most of the time you don't need to do that. If you simply want to run your runnable in a thread, new Thread(runnable).start() is plenty. If you need ui access (which you don't seem to) you'll need asynctasks or handlers

Comment: yeah, I DO need ui access, but I've written custom classes for the handlerthread and workerthread (which is what's getting called by the `mainCommunicationThread()` above. The weirdest thing is that this works on the 4.1 emulator, but not my 4.1 phone.

Comment: then chekc how asynctask works. you'll have background work on a separated thread, and callback on the ui thread when you are done

Comment: yeah, about 6 months ago, this function WAS using asynctask, but the aformentioned "ping-pong" of commands grew too massive, which is why I ported the whole thing over to custom handler/thread classes.  That's not really the issue here though, as I either get to that or not -- depending on this NetworkOnMainThread exceptoin

Comment: My biggest question is:  Is the above runnable STILL on the UI thread?

Comment: seems so. unless you give the handler a special looper

Comment: still, so strange that it works on EVERYTHING except my phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my solution:

```
public static InetAddress getInetAddressByName(String name)
{
    AsyncTask<String, Void, InetAddress> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, InetAddress>()
            {

                @Override
                protected InetAddress doInBackground(String... params)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
                    }
                    catch (UnknownHostException e)
                    {           
                        return null;
                    }                       
                }           
            };
    try
    {
        return task.execute(name).get();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: how to use this?

Answer (score 5):

you are trying to run in network operation in a runnable so either try to add this code in onCreate method:

```
     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

or i would suggest you to use asynctask instead of using Runnable thread

Comment: well that worked, but it concerns me.  It's like overriding that annoying bell in the car when your seatbelt isn't on.
I think I'll have to look deeper into this whole `looper.prepare()` thing.??  Or, are you suggesting I move the entire `StatControl` function inside the doInBackground() of the asynctask?

Comment: i would suggest you to move the entire StatsControl function inside doInBackground of AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Inet6Address.getLocalHost() NetworkOnMainThreadException problem by running that in a new thread.